# Throw dice till numbers are the same

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, dice, stopping-times, filtrations

Let's consider the following experience : we throw two dices till same number on two dices appears. I want to calculate expected sum of all dices appeared.

**My work so far**

I wanted to do it (and also I found it very intuitive) to do it by wold's decomposition theorem. The sum then will be presented by formula $E[S_n]=E[T]E[X_1]$, where $T$ is the stopping time.

*How to calculate $E[T]$ ?*

$P(Y=1)=\frac16$

$P(Y=2)=\frac56 \cdot \frac16$

$P(Y=n)=(\frac{5}{6})^{n-1} \cdot \frac16$

So :

$$E[Y]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i \cdot P(Y=i)=1 \cdot \frac16 +2 \cdot \frac56 \cdot \frac16+...$$

And it's type of series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i(1-p)^{i-1}p$ where $p \in [0,1]$ and this sum equals to $\frac1p$. So my sum above equals to 6 and that's exactly $E[T]$

why it would be good to use wold's theorem? Because it's very easy to calculate either $E[X_1]$ or $E[T]$ (calculated above). However, I don't know how should I define set $T=\inf\{...\}$ that will show that equality $E[S_n]=E[T]E[X_1]$ holds. I'm not sure how to strictly justify it.

Comment: No, For example if I have situation : 1,5 and 4,4 (so I should stop now, because the same number on two dices appeared). Then the sum of numbers appeared is $1+5+4+4=14$. I want to calculate expected value of this sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to just manually take all sums. The first part is where all of them are equal sums, the second is where one of them is $1$ and other is between $2$ and $6$, so on..

The last part is for the rolls to continue with $\frac{5}{6}$ probability.

It can surely be optimized but given it is just two dice, this works.

$E(X) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{36} (2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12) + \frac{2}{36}(3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) + \frac{2}{36}(5 + 6 + 7 + 8) + \frac{2}{36}(7 + 8 + 9) + \frac{2}{36} (9 + 10) + \frac{2}{36}(11) + \frac{5}{6}E(X).$

$E(X) = \displaystyle \frac{42}{36} + \frac{50}{36} + \frac{52}{36} + \frac{48}{36} + \frac{38}{36} + \frac{22}{36} + \frac{5}{6}E(X)$

$E(X) = \displaystyle \frac{252}{6} = 42$.

Comment: Hmmm, could you please explain more first equality ? It's not so clear for me why it holds.

Comment: @Lucian Just to clarify, you mean the first equation of $E(X)$? Why does it hold?

Comment: Exactly this one.

Comment: Especially appearance of term $E[X]$ on the right sight of the equation.

Comment: There are $36$ possible outcomes from $2$ dice and each with probability $\frac{1}{36}$. Each pair with same number on both happens with probability $1/36$ and hence I multiplied sum by that. Each pair of number other than equal can appear two ways and hence $2/36$ for each pair $(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1)$... now why $E(X)$ on the right. $1/6$ probability that the numbers will be same ($6$ pairs / $36$) and we stop. $5/6$ probability of getting a different pair and also the same probability that we continue rolling and add to our sum, hence addition of $\frac{5}{6} E(X)$ on the right..

Comment: Got it! Very clever and simple

Comment: You are welcome. To be more precise, if we do this indefinitely, you get an infinite geometric series $a+ar+ar^2..$ whose sum is given by $a/(1-r)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_1$ be the expected sum of a single throw given that the two dice are the same, and let $E_2$ be the expected sum of a single throw given that the two dice are different.

The probability that the two dice are the same is $\frac16$. So $E$, the expected total sum, satisfies
$$E=\frac16 E_1 + \frac56 (E_2+E)$$

And by linearity of expectation, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are both equal to $7$. So you can easily solve for $E$.

Answer (score 0):

From your work that $E[y]=6$ (on average it will take $6$ rolls of two dice):

You can say that you will have an average of $12$ single die rolls.

A single die roll has expected value $3.5$ (this is true even in the case that the die is part of a roll of doubles).

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I know what you trying to say but it's exactly what my queries are about. I'm looking for justification that equality $E[S_n]=E[T] \cdot E[X] = 6 \cdot 7 = 42$ holds

Comment: it's not so obvious in my opinion becuase maybe we should take into account that the dices cannot be the same. So instead of 36 possible outcomes we have only 30 so $E[S_n] \neq E[T]E[X_1]$